# SQL Server 2014 Management Studio Backup error

Tags: sql-server

I had installed Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Management Studio and had been working on a database for sometime now. My laptop had Windows 7 (64 bit) installed. And I had been taking regular backup on that machine and also stored the backup on an external drive.

Due to some reason my laptop stopped working. So now I started working on a different laptop. This other laptop has Windows 7 (32 bit) installed on it. I installed Microsoft SQL Sever 2014 Management Studio and restored my database using the `.bak` file.

I have been working on this database for sometime now and now the problem is when I try to take backup of my database I get this error:

[image: SQLServer Error]

Can someone please tell me how to resolve this error and how can I again take backup on this Windows 32 bit laptop?

Thanks

Comment: Why, why, why do you have a 32-bit OS installed anywhere? It's 2015, right?

Answer (score 5):

Change your Backup command to something like this

```
BACKUP DATABASE MyDB 
TO DISK = N'D:\MyDB.bak' 
WITH INIT, NOUNLOAD,  
     NAME = N'MyDB backup', STATS = 10, FORMAT
```

Notice the `FORMAT` at the end.

This should do it. You're changing `NOFORMAT` to `FORMAT` and remove `NOSKIP`

Comment: Another reason it's better to write a script than to use a the GUI.

Comment: I think also just writing to a new file (`WITH INIT`) rather than appending to the previous, existing backup will be the main solution.